# Any general method for iPad to output in 1080p when connected to TV by HDMI?

Tags: ipad, display, ipados

Is there any way for an iPad Air to output to the resolution of a 1080p TV (via HDMI converter) that is not app-specific?

I'm currently using an iPad Air with an adaptor that looks like this:
[image]

From the comments,
I am using a 16:9 screen, while the iPad is more of a 4:3 display.
As a result, there are black bars to the left and right when output to the television.

Comment: What iPad model and what HDMI converter are you using? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209186#displays suggests that iPadPro for example is actually able to output 4K videos.

Comment: Model: iPad Air, HDMI converter: Searchable on Amazon, "Apple Lightning Digital AV Adapter,1080P Lightning to HDMI Cable Sync Screen HDMI Connector Need Charging Power Support iPhone 11 Pro/XR/Xs/X/8/7 Plus,iPad to TV Projector Monitor Support All iOS"

Comment: This should work, however, this adaptor has quite a lot of bad reviews. I would try a different one. How are you determining that the current resolution is not 1080p?

Comment: I would assume 1080p would use up my entire TV widescreen like video game systems would. Currently, it does not use up the entire screen when connected and seems to be limited to the iPad model's native resolution.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the TV with iPad connected? It sounds to me as this is not a resolution issue, instead a screen ratio problem. I assume your TV is 16:9 and the iPads screen is 4:3, which will lead to big black bars on the right and left. Unfortunately iPads are not laptops and for the most part don't support something other than mirroring the native screen. Assuming from the image you also have an older iPad Air. Can you give the exact model number and the iOS version?

Comment: Yes, the iPad output is 4:3 as there are black bars on the right and left. As a compromise, I can also use a zoom function on the TV to make use of the full screen at the expense of resolution. Thanks, I'll just accept the limitations of the device and not expect too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments and based on actual results,
the iPad Air model I have has an output resolution strictly limited to the resolution of the screen.

As this screen has a lower resolution than my TV (where the screen is < 1080p), this translates to black bars appearing to the left and the right of the display on the TV.
In addition, the output frame rate is noticeably worse with such an output adaptor shown in the original post, showing a 30 FPS video at around 20 FPS.

There is no known software fix to this as it is a limitation imposed by the hardware itself.

Alternatively, I can zoom in the TV to make use of the full screen, at the cost of even worse resolution with the lower output video frame rate even more noticeable.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks for posting a follow up.

Comment: Most modern iPads have a resolution of 2048x1536px, which is higher than a 1080p TV. The framerate limit might be an unfortunate limitation of lightning ports. Perhaps more recent models support higher framerates, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

AirPlay can push to 4K resolution but you need an Apple TV or other intermediary. Even plugging the latest    iPad Pro in to USB-C devices that are 4K displays, the OS doesn’t run the resolution you ask. It has to be app specific programming to kick the GPU portion of the Apple Silicon chips to higher resolution via network or USB port.

Answer (score 2):

I expect that your iPad Air does in fact have a higher resolution than 1080p (2048x1536px I think), but the general logic in iOS dictates that unless some app-specific work has been done to determine how to treat the external display, it will mirror the device content in a way that reflects the 4:3 aspect ratio.

In my experience with an iPad Pro 12.9" 2nd gen, the default mirroring behaviour means black bars are added not just to the sides, but also the top & bottom of the screen. It seems this may be because of overscan compensation that is applied by default in the OS.

Some apps (for example Netflix) do use the full extent of the external display.

I have been developing an app, in which I also take care to display full-resolution content on the external display. Even when ostensibly displaying at 1080p, it was still adding black bars to all sides of the output until I explicitly disabled the overscan compensation (took a while to suss that one out!). What I am now finding, though, is that while the dimensions match, the visual quality of the resulting signal from my device is quite significantly degraded, as if my content had a relatively low-bitrate video encoding applied.

According to [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ipad/comments/lb39go/can_i_stream_a_4k_video_on_my_4k_monitor_via_hdmi/), this is due to Lightning being a bottleneck (only USB 2 bandwidth). As such, the content is encoded to mp4 before being decoded by the HDMI adapter.